# Print Server Forgetting Printers

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, printing, network-printer, shared-printers

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 server setup with the print and document services role installed.  From here, this machine is domain attached to a mixed domain environment that has some Windows Server 2003 domain controllers and some Windows Server 2008 domain controllers.

I have setup the printers, ports, and drivers within the Windows Server 2008 R2 print server.  Next, I published these printers to the directory by selecting the printer, right-clicking on it, and selecting list in the directory.

A few minutes later, I take a separate domain attached Windows 7 Pro machine and go to devices and printers. I select add a printer, use a network or wireless printer, the printer I wanted was not listed here, select find a printer in the directory, and am able to see the printer in the list of domain attached printers to select and install on my machine.

I can wait a few days, go to another Windows 7 Pro machine and follow the same process to locate the same printer; however, the printers I listed in the directory are no longer able to be searched for in the directory.  No other changes have resulted in the day or two between tests (at least that I am aware of).

I was curious what would cause this?  Is there something that I am doing wrong?  What would make the printers disappear from being found in the directory?  Interestingly, I am able to select the printer, remove it from being listed in the directory, add it or list it back in the directory and the same process will start back all over again where you see it for a day or two and then it disappears.

Comment: At the Add Printer > Add a network, wireless or Bluetooth printer > Add Printer window, what is the source of the list of printers that appears in the Select a printer list? How do I add my printers that I flagged to "List in Directory" to this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up needing the change some of the group policy settings in relation to the pruning of the printers.  Also, there appears to be some weirdness that exists in relation to the SNMP polling/monitoring with Windows 7 and printers.